# Why is my mesh deforming like this?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, vertex-groups

Okay, I have a downloaded model here. I’ve decided to let the model wear a suit (like almost full body one). So, I decided to edit the model’s clothes. However, the original model was wearing long baggy trousers. I removed it and remodeled the leg (the original mesh has no thigh, only have hips, shin and feet. It was covered by the trousers).

I tried joining the hips with the shin by making a new mesh in between. I made the leg as close to the other models that work perfectly and made sure they have the same structure and the edges in the right place. Since the most parts of the leg is a new mesh, I assigned it manually as vertex groups to the bones, using other model’s vertex groups as reference (because somehow automatic weights don’t work).

When I tested it out, it was like this…
[image]

Here is an example of the way it is supposed to deform. Below is the legs of the model I used as a reference to build the legs and assign vertex groups with:
[image]

Is this because I assigned the vertex groups wrongly? I couldn’t find any errors in the vertex groups so far. Or is ti something else? If you need more info, please tell me and I’ll show you if possible.

Comment: Yes. You have a weight painting error.  The vertices that are moving wrong are either not in any group or are weighted in groups they don't belong in.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to assign the meshes again. If I've got any more problems I'll comment again.

Comment: If you have more problems, edit your question, because comments get lost.  It would help if you included screenshots showing the weights of the areas that aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Want to improve this post? Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.
This post is hidden. It was deleted 7 hours ago by Duarte Farrajota Ramos♦.
I've did bone weight painting again and I've got it fixed. So there.

I've adjusted the weights for the hips, thigh, shin, foot and toe

Hips:[image]

Thigh:[image]

Shin:[image]

Foot:[image]

Toe:[image]